# mysql select row based in many column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id alias_word language  original
1    word1      es      changed_word
2    word1      en      orig_word
3    word1      fr      changed_word
4    word2      de      other_original
```

Supposing reference column `language` = `es`

How to make a query to have result all rows that have `alias_word` column = `word1` and the `original` column is different than `original` column where `language` column = es

espected result:

`2    word1    en    orig_word`

Ihave tried this and have empty result

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE alias_word = 'word1' AND original <> original
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a self join:

```
SELECT w2.*
FROM words w1
INNER JOIN words w2
    ON w1.alias_word = w2.alias_word AND
       w1.original <> w2.original
WHERE
    w1.language = 'es';
```

### Demo

Comment: Ok. thank's ... It work. I have added `WHERE  w1.language = 'es' AND w1.alias = 'my_wanted_alias';` to adapt at my needs

Answer (score 0):

`AND original <> original` Will always return nothing. I don't quite follow what you are doing with that original column, but I think you want to not have the word 'original' in the original column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM words 
WHERE alias_word = 'word1' 
    AND original <> 'original'
    AND language = 'es'
```

Comment: This works for the particular example in the OP, but does so by hard coding values.

Comment: Here something not ok ... `AND original <> 'original'` ... I can't know the value of original ... this must be something `AND original <> 'I_need_this_value_by_one_query_where_language_es'`